# Playscape SDK and Unity 4.5.5 fails APK build with ParseException "class name does not match path"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, playscape

With last version of Playscape SDK i get error  "ParseException: class name  does not match path ".

I think problem is in android-project inside folder: Assets\Plugins\Android\PlayscapePublishingKit

Can this project conflicts with Assets\Plugins\Android\AndroidManifest.xml?

Error:

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details.
c:\work\java\7\bin\java.exe -Xmx1024M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/work/android/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:/work/warbots/Unity/Unity455/Editor/Data/BuildTargetTools/AndroidPlayer\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:129)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (com/Playscape/Xenobot_2/Manifest$permission) does not match path (com/playscape/Xenobot_2/Manifest$permission.class)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:520)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

All letters in your bundle identifier should be in lower case